# How to implement DBSCAN clustering in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I'm looking for a way to cluster set of features with `DBSCAN` algorithm in tensorflow however I'm unable to find anything related.

`TensorFlow` offers K-Means clustering (tf.contrib.learn.KMeansClustering), but I need `DBSCAN` algorithm.

Can anybody suggest me any existing wrappers written in `python/java`?

Any pointers on how to implement it from scratch?

P.S. I am aware of sklearn and similar libraries that has `DBSCAN`, but I specifically need in `TensorFlow`.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm like a year late to the party, but for any future reference:
[here](https://github.com/pmarcol/dbscan_tf) is my implementation of DBSCAN-like algorithm. It might give results slightly different from what you'd get from algorithm implemented in sklearn, for example, especially for observations that may belong to more than one clusters.
I know it's probably not optimal.
I know, that TF is not the best choice when it comes to implementing the algorithm.
But maybe someone will find the code valuable.

Relevant code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def run(vals, epsilon=4, min_points=4):

    def merge_core_points_into_clusters(elems):
        row = elems
        mat = core_points_connection_matrix
        nonempty_intersection_inds = tf.where(tf.reduce_any(tf.logical_and(row, mat), axis=1))
        cumul = tf.logical_or(row, mat)
        subcumul = tf.gather_nd(cumul, nonempty_intersection_inds)
        return tf.reduce_any(subcumul, axis=0)

    def label_clusters(elems):
        return tf.reduce_min(tf.where(elems))

    def get_subsets_for_labels(elems):
        val = elems[0]
        labels = elems[1]
        conn = relation_matrix

        inds = tf.where(tf.equal(labels, val))
        masks = tf.gather_nd(conn, inds)
        return tf.reduce_any(masks, axis=0)

    def scatter_labels(elems):
        label = tf.expand_dims(elems[0], 0)
        mask = elems[1]
        return label*tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.int64)

    data_np = np.array(vals)

    eps = epsilon
    min_pts = min_points

    in_set = tf.placeholder(tf.float64)

    # distance matrix
    r = tf.reduce_sum(in_set*in_set, 1)
    # turn r into column vector
    r = tf.reshape(r, [-1, 1])
    dist_mat = tf.sqrt(r - 2*tf.matmul(in_set, tf.transpose(in_set)) + tf.transpose(r))

    # for every point show, which points are within eps distance of that point (including that point)
    relation_matrix = dist_mat <= eps

    # number of points within eps-ball for each point
    num_neighbors = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(relation_matrix, tf.int64), axis=1)

    # for each point show, whether this point is core point
    core_points_mask = num_neighbors >= min_pts

    # indices of core points
    core_points_indices = tf.where(core_points_mask)

    core_points_connection_matrix = tf.cast(core_points_mask, dtype=tf.int64) * tf.cast(relation_matrix, dtype=tf.int64)
    core_points_connection_matrix = tf.cast(core_points_connection_matrix, dtype=tf.bool)
    core_points_connection_matrix = tf.logical_and(core_points_connection_matrix, core_points_mask)

    merged = tf.map_fn(
        merge_core_points_into_clusters,
        core_points_connection_matrix,
        dtype=tf.bool
    )

    nonempty_clusters_records = tf.gather_nd(merged, core_points_indices)

    marked_core_points = tf.map_fn(label_clusters, nonempty_clusters_records, dtype=tf.int64)

    _, labels_core_points = tf.unique(marked_core_points, out_idx=tf.int64)

    labels_core_points = labels_core_points+1

    unique_labels, _ = tf.unique(labels_core_points)

    labels_all = tf.scatter_nd(
        tf.cast(core_points_indices, tf.int64),
        labels_core_points,
        shape=tf.cast(tf.shape(core_points_mask), tf.int64)
    )

    # for each label return mask, which points should have this label
    ul_shape = tf.shape(unique_labels)
    labels_tiled = tf.maximum(tf.zeros([ul_shape[0], 1], dtype=tf.int64), labels_all)

    labels_subsets = tf.map_fn(
        get_subsets_for_labels,
        (unique_labels, labels_tiled),
        dtype=tf.bool
    )

    final_labels = tf.map_fn(
        scatter_labels,
        elems=(tf.expand_dims(unique_labels, 1), labels_subsets),
        dtype=tf.int64
    )

    final_labels = tf.reduce_max(final_labels, axis=0)

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        results = (sess.run(final_labels, feed_dict={in_set:data_np})).reshape((1, -1))

    results = results.reshape((-1, 1))

    return results
```

Comment: Please add relevant parts of your link here.

Comment: Yes, I did some benchmarking, but only on CPU, unfortunately. I do not remember the details, but it was much slower.

Comment: Update: I have just cursorily tested it on 100 and 1000 data points (2 features each) and it seems like there is difference of ~3 orders of magnitude in favor of the sklearn's implementation. Details (obtained with %%timeit in Jupyter):  
100 points: 118ms (TF) vs 925 µs (sklearn); 1000 points:  22.4s (TF) vs 7.9ms (sklearn). It would be nice to see how much a decent GPU could improve the performance of the implementation in TF.

Comment: any upgrade to tf v2.x?

Comment: @LuisFelipe unfortunately not, I'm sorry to admit that I haven't maintained the repository for quite a long time. But feel free to fork or even contribute to the repo.